# Issue in Eclipse: Cannot get a DefaultScreenDevice -> cannot launch any GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, awt, nvidia

An issue appeared recently when launching Java code **from within Eclipse** in Windows 10 platform; I googled for help without success.

As of now, I cannot launch any Java application that would rely on Swing or AWT. For instance If I launch such an application from a `main` method, it exists without an error message.

I debugged into the issue a little bit and I found that the faulty line was in the `Window.class` of AWT, when initializing the `GraphicsEnvironment` (line 471-482 in jsk 1.8.121):

```
private GraphicsConfiguration initGC(GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
    GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless();

    if (gc == null) {
        gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().
            getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }
    setGraphicsConfiguration(gc);

    return gc;
}
```

A `main` method used to debug the issue like this:

```
    public static void main( final String[] args )
{
    System.out.println( "Launching stuff" );
    final GraphicsEnvironment localGraphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    System.out.println( localGraphicsEnvironment ); // DEBUG
    final GraphicsDevice defaultScreenDevice = localGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    System.out.println( defaultScreenDevice ); // DEBUG
    final GraphicsConfiguration defaultConfiguration = defaultScreenDevice.getDefaultConfiguration();
    System.out.println( defaultConfiguration ); // DEBUG

    System.out.println( "Launched" );
}
```

prints:

`Launching ImageJ
sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment@27bc2616`

and that's it.

---

I tried to update the jdk to the latest one (on win-x64 platform) with no success. Updating Eclipse to the latest does not work either (I tried Mars 2 and Neon). 
I suspect some issue with the graphic drivers (since I cannot get a default screen service), but I am up to date as well (NVIdia Geforce Experience updater), and the device manager reports no issue.

The issue is recent, it appeared 6 days ago maximum. In this time, I have graphic driver updates, including Vulkan maybe. 
I am a lost since it means I cannot develop on this system anymore.

Anyone as leads I could follow to address this issue?

Best
jy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the possible responsible for this.

I noticed I updated my NVidia drivers (I have a Geforce GTX970) earlier that week and that I had installed their drivers for 3D vision in the process.

Uninstalling the later fixed the problem.

Comment: This was my problem too. I had NVidia GTX580 with Java 1.8.0_91 to 1.8.0_212. I debugged the problem to the same line of AWT code where the JFrame was created, somewhere internally there was a System exist with value -107374079 . Uninstalling the NVidia 3D Vision magically solved the problem. Many thanks!